# Powershell script does not run in Java code

Tags: java, powershell

I have a simple script and I want to call it from my Java code. The script does not run properly.

The script is very simple: 
mkdir 0000000;

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    String path = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe";
    String command = "C:\\test\\test.ps1";
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = runtime.exec(path + " " + command);
    proc.destroy();
}
```

The dir "0000000" is not created. I use JDK 7, windows 10.

Any suggestion would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Remove `proc.destroy();`.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers: That's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the code as below and finally it worked!

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String path = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe";
        String command1 ="cmd /c \"cd C:\\test && " + path + " /c .\\test.ps1\"";
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = runtime.exec(command1);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        proc.destroy();
    }
```

Comment: Using a `Thread.sleep(2000)` while leaving `proc.destroy()` in place is setting a hard timeout for the external command, meaning the command *will* be terminated after 2 seconds, regardless of whether it has finished or not. To wait for the completion of an external command use `waitFor()` as described in my answer. The change to the commandline (running `powershell.exe` from CMD instead of running it directly) is not required.

Answer (score 1):

`exec()` runs the process asynchronously, so the subsequent `proc.destroy()` terminates it right away before it can do anything. If you run the program from an interactive shell simply removing `proc.destroy()` would mitigate the issue, but to actually fix it you need to wait for the external process to finish. You may also want to catch the exception `exec()` (or `waitFor()`) could throw.

```
import java.io.*;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    String path = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe";
    String command = "C:\\test\\test.ps1";
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process proc = runtime.exec(path + " " + command);
        proc.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // do exception handling here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that does not work. destroy() was a part of the problem. The command itself should be changed too.

Comment: @DanielSmith There was a semicolon missing after the import statement, and I didn't account for the exception `waitFor()` throws. Both issues are fixed now. The code is tested and does work. Changing the command string is not required.

Comment: Which OS do you use? I use win10 and this does not work on it. proc.waitFor sometimes makes a lot of problems, in my case I prefer the 2 seconds delay.

Comment: @DanielSmith I ran it on Windows 7 with JDK 8. I just tested it again on Windows 10 with JDK 7. Same result: the code I posted works perfectly fine. It does require the execution policy to actually allow running PowerShell scripts, of course, but if that was the issue, the code from your answer wouldn't work either.